# Class called RGB in Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm working on a cross-platform open-source project. Up till now it was not a problem to have a class called `RGB` in namespace `rgb`. Now I observe a strange problem with the Microsoft compiler (VS 2010).

When I declare the class, the preprocessor complains about a macro being misused. I get it that a crude `RGB` macro is defined in WinGdi.h. Whoever found that reasonable, but whatever. So at the top of rgb.h I do:

```
#undef RGB

namespace rgb {

  class RGB : public shell::Command {
  public:
    RGB();
  };
}
```

This solves the problem for compiling the rgb.cpp object. However, at another place I  want to instantiate an object:

```
#include "rgb.h"

namespace shell {

  Modules::Modules() {
    Command *c;
    c = new rgb::RGB(); // errors at this line
  }
}
```

I get the error messages:
Error   19  error C2589: '(' : illegal token on right side of '::'
Error   20  error C2059: syntax error : '::'
at the denoted line

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Are you missing a semicolon after your class declaration?

Comment: Thanks, but no, only in the example. My code compiles with GCC.

Comment: Are you covering all sources including "WinGdi.h" in some way? Just rename that RGB (which looks like a macro anyway) to something else (maybe Rgb).

Comment: Don't name your class like a macro

Comment: Vote this up please: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/6656174-have-a-version-of-windows-h-that-doesn-t-define-ma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Rename RGB in your source.
2. Wrap WinGdi.h. Create files MyWinGdi.h and MyWinGdi.cpp. Include WinGdi.h from MyWinGdi.cpp. For any functions/definitions you need from WinGdi.h, define them in MyWinGdi.h and declare them in MyWinGdi.cpp to call the real functions. This might be tricky for constants.
3. Take a copy of WinGdi.h and put it in your source so that it gets chosen as the include before the one from the SDK. Hack it by commenting out the RGB macro.
4. To help diagnose the issue. Use command line options to generate a source file after pre-processing, and see how macros get expanded around your error if any.
5. Vote up the post I just put on uservoice and try and get Microsoft to fix their headers.
   http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/6656174-have-a-version-of-windows-h-that-doesn-t-define-ma

Comment: Ok options 2 and 3 are not suitable for me. I hate option 1, but if I cannot avoid it in a sane way...

Comment: @ypnos - Yes, I hate it too, but that's what I've always ended up doing when I've had similar problems.

Answer (score 3):

Undefining system macros is a horrible practice and I strongly suggest not to do it. That said, I would just change the `RGB` name of your class not to clash with the system macro.

Include guards and inclusion hierarchies might create problems with `undef`'ining things.

If you really want to keep the same name as the macro's one, just instruct the preprocessor **not** to expand your class function calls and constructor:

```
#define RGB(r,g,b)  whatever..

namespace rgb {
    class RGB {
    public:
        (RGB)() {} // "Dear preprocessor, please don't expand this"
    };
}

void hello() {
    auto c = new (rgb::RGB)(); // Ditto
}
```

Comment: class (RGB) too I assume

Comment: @pm100 It's not necessary to be honest since a tag name can't be expanded

Comment: @pm100 It isn't necessary [(see it live)](http://ideone.com/XIK5aL).Its a macro-arg thing (more precisely, indicating a forced lack thereof.)